Evaluating the inverse trigonometric integral $\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\arctan{\left(at\right)}}{1+t^{2}}$ in terms of polylogarithms

Define the function $\mathcal{J}:\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral
$$\mathcal{J}{\left(a,z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\arctan{\left(at\right)}}{1+t^{2}}.$$
The $a=1$ case is of course elementary:
$$\mathcal{J}{\left(1,z\right)}=\left[\arctan{\left(z\right)}\right]^{2};~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}}.$$
When $a\neq1$, an antiderivative for the integrand of $\mathcal{J}$ can be found in terms of logarithms and dilogarithms of complex arguments. However, I would like to obtain an expression for $\mathcal{J}$ in terms of purely real functions. This should be possible since the dilogarithm of a complex argument can be reduced to Clausen functions and the following two-variable variant of the dilogarithm:
$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\varphi\right)}:=-\frac12\int_{0}^{r}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+x^{2}\right)}}{x};~~~\small{\left(r,\varphi\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}}.$$

Problem: Derive a closed-form expression for $\mathcal{J}{\left(a,z\right)}$ in terms of real functions (preferably without using complex variables as an intermediary step, or we'd just use the antiderivative found by WolframAlpha).


Note: Some relatively easy to prove functional relations for the two-variable dilogarithm that could be useful below include
$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,0\right)}=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r\right)};~~~\small{r\in(-\infty,1]},$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\varphi\right)}=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,2n\pi\pm\varphi\right)};~~~\small{n\in\mathbb{Z}\land\left(r,\varphi\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}},$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=\frac14\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r^{2}\right)};~~~\small{r\in\mathbb{R}},$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\varphi\right)}=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r,\pi-\varphi\right)};~~~\small{\left(r,\varphi\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}},$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\varphi\right)}=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\frac14\left(\pi-\varphi\right)^{2};~~~\small{0\le\varphi\le2\pi}.$$



For $(a,z)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}$, we find
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}{\left(a,z\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\arctan{\left(at\right)}}{1+t^{2}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{t}{1+x^{2}t^{2}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2t}{\left(1+x^{2}t^{2}\right)\left(1+t^{2}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2t}{\left(1+x^{2}t^{2}\right)\left(1+t^{2}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{z^{2}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}u\right)\left(1+u\right)};~~~\small{\left[t^{2}=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{z^{2}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}\left[\frac{1}{1+u}-\frac{x^{2}}{1+x^{2}u}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{z^{2}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{d}{du}\left[\ln{\left(1+u\right)}-\ln{\left(1+x^{2}u\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\left[\ln{\left(1+z^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(1+z^{2}x^{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{1+z^{2}}{1+z^{2}x^{2}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$
Noting that $-1<\frac{1-a}{1+a}<1$ for $0<a$ and $-1<\frac{1-z^{2}}{1+z^{2}}<1$ for $0<z$, and setting
$$A:=\frac{1-a}{1+a}\land\omega:=2\arctan{\left(z\right)},$$
we then have $0<z\implies0<\omega<\pi\implies z=\tan{\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)}\implies\frac{1-z^{2}}{1+z^{2}}=\cos{\left(\omega\right)}$, and so
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}{\left(a,z\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{1+z^{2}}{1+z^{2}x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{1}^{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{(-2)}{\left(1+y\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)\left(\frac{2}{1+y}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1+z^{2}}{1+z^{2}\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right]}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{2y}\ln{\left(\frac{1+z^{2}}{1+z^{2}\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{2y}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1+z^{2}\right)\left(1+y\right)^{2}}{\left(1+y\right)^{2}+z^{2}\left(1-y\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{2y}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1+z^{2}\right)\left(1+y\right)^{2}}{\left(1+z^{2}\right)+2\left(1-z^{2}\right)y+\left(1+z^{2}\right)y^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{2y}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1+y\right)^{2}}{1+2\left(\frac{1-z^{2}}{1+z^{2}}\right)y+y^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{A}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{2y}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1+y\right)^{2}}{1+2y\cos{\left(\omega\right)}+y^{2}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$
We then obtain
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}{\left(a,z\right)}
&=\int_{A}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{2y}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1+y\right)^{2}}{1+2y\cos{\left(\omega\right)}+y^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{A}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{2y}\left[2\ln{\left(1+y\right)}-\ln{\left(1+2y\cos{\left(\omega\right)}+y^{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{A}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}-\int_{A}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+2y\cos{\left(\omega\right)}+y^{2}\right)}}{2y}\\
&=-\int_{-1}^{-A}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x};~~~\small{\left[y=-x\right]}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{A}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+2y\cos{\left(\omega\right)}+y^{2}\right)}}{2y}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-A\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\int_{1}^{A}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2y\cos{\left(\pi-\omega\right)}+y^{2}\right)}}{2y}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-A\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2y\cos{\left(\pi-\omega\right)}+y^{2}\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{A}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2y\cos{\left(\pi-\omega\right)}+y^{2}\right)}}{y}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-A\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\pi-\omega\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(A,\pi-\omega\right)}\\
&=\frac14\omega^{2}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-A\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(A,\pi-\omega\right)}\\
&=\left[\arctan{\left(z\right)}\right]^{2}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a},\pi-2\arctan{\left(z\right)}\right)}\\
&=\left[\arctan{\left(z\right)}\right]^{2}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{1-a}{1+a},2\arctan{\left(z\right)}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

