How to find closed form $\int^1_0\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+3x^2}dx$
I need help to find the closed form this integral :
$$\int^1_0\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+3x^2}dx$$
My attempt
\begin{align*}I & =\int^1_0\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+3x^2}dx =\int^1_0\int^1_0\frac{x}{(1+3x^2)(1+(xy)^2)}dydx \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\int^1_0\frac{1}{(1+3x)(1+xy^2)}dxdy\\&= \frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{1}{3-y^2}\int^1_0 \left({\frac{3}{1+3x}-\frac{y^2}{1+xy^2}}\right)dxdy \\&= \frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{\ln\left({\frac{4}{1+y^2}}\right)}{3-y^2}dy=\ln(2)\int^1_0\frac{1}{3-y^2} dy - \frac{1}{2}\int^2_0\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{3-y}dy\\&= \frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt 3}\tanh^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}}\right)- \frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{3-y}dy
\end{align*}
Now the problem is to find the closed form of this other integral.
$$\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{3-y}dy$$
$$\textbf{I need a little help here.}$$

Could you explain how you grët  the second double integral from the first? That equality seems a bit strange to me.

we have $\arctan(x)=\int^1_0\frac{x}{1+(xy)^2} dy $  and $dx dy = dy dx$ and Let x:= x^2

This is a special case of this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4949300/evaluating-the-inverse-trigonometric-integral-int-0z-mathrmdt-frac2

Hint
$$I=\int\frac{\log(1+y^2)}{3-y}\,dy=\int\frac{\log(y+i)}{3-y}\,dy+\int\frac{\log(y-i)}{3-y}\,dy$$
Use
$$\int \frac{\log(y+a)}{b-y}\,dy=-\log (a+y)\, \log \left(\frac{b-y}{a+b}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+y}{a+b}\right)$$ Use it twice with $a=\pm i$ and $b=3$.

Yes I thought about it and did it but I thought there was a better way.

@Abd-ElouahabMoustapha. You cannot avoid polylogarithms.

More generally
\begin{align}\int_0^{1}& \frac{\tan^{-1} x}{1+a^{2}x^2}{dx}
=\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac x{(a^{2}x^2+1)(y^2x^2+1)}dy\ dx\\
&\>\>\>\>\> = \frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \frac {1+a^2}{1+y^2}}{a^2-y^2}dy 
=\frac1{2a}\Re \bigg[\text{Li}_2\bigg( \frac{a+1}{a-i}\bigg)-\text{Li}_2\bigg( \frac{a-1}{a+i}\bigg)\bigg]
\end{align}
As a special case, $a= \sqrt3$
$$\int_0^{1}\frac{\tan^{-1} x}{1+3x^2}{dx}
= \frac1{2\sqrt3}\Re \bigg[\text{Li}_2\bigg( \frac{\sqrt3 +1}{\sqrt3-i}\bigg)-\text{Li}_2\bigg( \frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+i}\bigg)\bigg]
$$
